# How to solve these errors ? _this2.state is not a function & _this3.state is not a function?

Tags: react-native, expo

I need to solve these errors..

First, if I click the login button it throw me back error => 
_this2.state is not a function

and

Second, if I click the signup button it throw me back error => 
_this3.state is not a function

How to solve this problem?

---

## this is my code down below

```
export default class LoginScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        email: '',
        password: '',
        error: '',
        loading: false,
    };

    this.onLoginPress = this.onLoginPress.bind(this);
    this.onSignUpPress = this.onSignUpPress.bind(this);
  }

  onLoginPress() {
    this.setState({ error:'', loading:true });

    const {email, password} = this.state;
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(()=> {
        this.state({error:'', loading:false});
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile');
    }) 
    .catch(()=>{
        this.state({error:'Authentication Failed!', loading:false})
    })
  }

  onSignUpPress() {
    this.setState({ error:'', loading:true });

    const {email, password} = this.state;
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(()=> {
        this.state({error:'', loading:false});
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile');
    }) 
    .catch(()=>{
        this.state({error:'Authentication Failed!', loading:false})
    })
  }

  renderButtonOrLoading(){
    if( this.state.loading ){
        return <Text>Loading ...</Text>
    } else {
        return(
            <View>
                <Button 
                title="Login" 
                onPress={this.onLoginPress}/>
                <Button 
                title="Sign Up" 
                onPress={this.onSignUpPress}/>
            </View>
        );
    }
  }

  render() {
    return(
        <View>
            <FormLabel>Email</FormLabel>
            <FormInput onChangeText={email => this.setState({email})}/>
            <FormLabel>Password</FormLabel>
            <FormInput onChangeText={password => this.setState({password})}/>
            <FormValidationMessage>Error Message</FormValidationMessage>
            { this.renderButtonOrLoading() }
        </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You have to bind(this)  to this function as well: renderButtonOrLoading()

Comment: like this ?

 <Button 
                    title="Login" 
                    onPress={this.onLoginPress.bind(this)}/>
                    <Button 
                    title="Sign Up" 
                    onPress={this.onSignUpPress.bind(this)}/>

Comment: but still not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Bind renderButtonOrLoading with this or use arrow function.
2. In onLoginPress and onSignUpPress functions, replace this.state({error:'', loading:false}) with
   this.setState({ error: '', loading: false });

Let me know if it works.

Comment: did you change this.state({error:'Authentication Failed!', loading:false}) also to this.setState({error:'Authentication Failed!', loading:false}) in both the functions?

Comment: yup, already do it 

onLoginPress()
// Fix below line
      this.setState({error:'Authentication Failed!', loading:false})

onSignUpPress()
// Fix below line
      this.setState({error:'Authentication Failed!', loading:false})

Comment: Where did you bind renderButtonOrLoading and what's the error after doing the above fix?

Comment: owhh, its solved already sir..

omg, i am not to enabled email authentication in firebase earlier..

but your advice is very helpful me :))

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `this.state` in the `onLoginPress` and `onSignUpPress` to `this.setState`

```
onLoginPress() {
  this.setState({ error:'', loading:true });

  const {email, password} = this.state;
  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(()=> {
      // Fix below line
      this.setState({error:'', loading:false});
      this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile');
    }) 
    .catch(()=>{
      // Fix below line
      this.setState({error:'Authentication Failed!', loading:false})
    })
  }

  onSignUpPress() {
    this.setState({ error:'', loading:true });

    const {email, password} = this.state;
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(()=> {
      // Fix below line
      this.setState({error:'', loading:false});
      this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile');
    }) 
    .catch(()=>{
      // Fix below line
      this.setState({error:'Authentication Failed!', loading:false})
    })
  }
```

Comment: owhh, its solved already sir..

omg, i am not to enabled email authentication in firebase earlier..

but your advice is very helpful me :))

Thanks in advance